# Java | storing image from URL | java.io.IOException: 403 for URL

Tags: java, image, http-status-code-403, ioexception

Other images work, but apparently not this one.

https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Inspirational-Images/large/Isaiah_55-6.jpg

Code:

```
public static void imageFromURL(URL url, String saveAs) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection httpURLCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpURLCon.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76");
    BufferedImage c = ImageIO.read(url.openStream());
    File outputFile = new File("C:.../resources/" + saveAs);
    ImageIO.write(c, "jpg", outputFile);
}
```

Error Message:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Inspirational-Images/large/Isaiah_55-6.jpg
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1840)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at MainActivity.imageFromURL(MainActivity.java:41)
    at MainActivity.main(MainActivity.java:49)
```

Have tried other resolves such as:

```
HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
httpcon.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76");
```

---

```
uc = url.openConnection();
uc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", 
"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
```

---

```
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already opened a connection to the image URL and stored it in `httpURLCon`.

Reuse that connection, because that's the one for which you've set the user agent:

```
HttpURLConnection httpURLCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpURLCon.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76");
BufferedImage c = ImageIO.read(httpURLCon.getInputStream());
```

Comment: Changing the openStream()  to getInputStream() seemed to help a lot.